# Complementary of a convex set and restrictive limits

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, limits, convex-analysis

In general the following theorem is false.

> Let $U = \cup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} U_n$ be unbounded open sets of $\mathbb{C}$ and $f$ a function defined on $U$. Assume that $\lim_{z\to \infty, z \in U_n} f(z) =0$ for all $n$. Then $\lim_{z\to \infty, z \in U} f(z) =0$

I would be interested in a specific case where this theorem could be true. Assume that $U$ is the complementary of a convex closed set $S \subset \mathbb{C}.$ Then $U$ can be written as the union of a countable number of halfplanes. (Let us note them $U_n$)

Is the previous theorem true in this context ? If not, what are possibly the hypothesis we need to add ?

Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by $z\to \infty$?

Comment: $|z|$ becomes arbitrarily big.

Comment: Now you have edited the problem! ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is always the case when the convex set $S$ you are talking about is compact. However, in general no. Consider $\Bbb C=\Bbb R^2$ and the convex set $S=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,:\, x> 0\wedge xy\ge1\}$. In this case, say, we can take an enumeration $q_n$ of $\Bbb Q^+$ and consider $U=\Bbb R^2\setminus S=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N} U_n$ with $U_n=\left\{(x,y)\,:\,y+\frac x{q_n^2}-\frac1{q_n}< 0\right\}$.

Then, we can consider a $C^\infty$ function $f:\Bbb R^2\to\Bbb R$ such that $f\left(\frac1n,\frac n2\right)=n$ (or the quantity you prefer) and $f(x,y)=0$ for $x\le 0\vee y\le 0$. This represents a counterexample to your claim, because $U_n\cap\{x\ge 0\wedge y\ge 0\}$ is relatively compact, and therefore $$\lim_{\lvert (x,y)\rvert\to\infty\\ (x,y)\in U_n} f(x,y)=\lim_{\lvert (x,y)\rvert\to\infty\\(x,y)\in U_n\\ x<0\vee y<0} f(x,y)=0$$
while $\limsup_{\begin{matrix}\lvert (x,y)\rvert\to\infty\\ (x,y)\in U\end{matrix}}f(x,y)\ge\limsup_{k\to\infty} f\left(\frac1k,\frac k2\right)=+\infty$

**Added:** It might be worth mentioning that this example works for any possible covering of $\Bbb R^2\setminus S$ in open half-planes, be them countably many or not.